# DFS algorithm and how do I show/put it into practice?

Tags: algorithms

I'm new to DFS algorithm and I'm trying to figure it out.

The main concepts I get from it is that you have a stack of nodes, and they have a value, and can contain children-nodes (Even called branches or leaves) that can contains nodes with values.

So let's say that I have a Tree containing 15 nodes like this.

[image]

I would understand that the algorithm goes A-N-O-B-D-J-L-M-K-C-E-F-H-G-I, If you were to go in alphabetic order.

My confusion is this how to put this algorithm into practice **(such as coding it)**. How should I see this tree like (Array, List?)

And if some of the children are connected to each other can it still be a DFS algorithm?
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. DFS is a well-defined algorithm that works perfectly well when the graph isn't a tree. And, although implementation questions are off-topic, here, you'd implement the tree/graph using any appropriate data structure.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes I can understand now to why my question is confusing. In this case I was asking in how I should think regarding implementing DFS to code. How should I implement the tree structure in the best-case scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is pick a *data structure* - i.e a representation for your node graph.  For this I suggest you pick up any undergraduate-level book on data structures and read it carefully, and choose something appropriate.  For example, given the tree above, I would represent each node with a record containing whatever data is to be stored in that node *(e.g the name - A, B, etc)* plus a list of (pointers to) child nodes.  E.g your root would have the list {A, B, C}, node A would have the list {N}, node J would have the list {K, L, M}, and so on.  Each childless node ('leaf') would have an empty list.

Then you code your DFS procedure, which you may find easier to do if you use recursion to process children (although there are ways to make this non-recursive if you insist).  Regardless of implementation, the *core behavior* of DFS is: To process each node, you must do something with the node, then scan the list of children and process each child -and its entire subtree- before processing the next child.  You can get different effects according to whether you process each node before its children, or after *[if each node has at most two children AND explicitly distinguishes 'left' child from 'right' child, then there is also the option of processing each node -between- left and right]*.

And yes, you can still perform DFS if there are cross-connections.  The key new thing to do here is to keep track of whether the node you are about to process *has already been processed*; generally what you will want to do in that case is skip that node and go back up to the parent.  This is particularly true if 'children' really means 'neighbors', so the edges between nodes aren't *directed*; then you really need to avoid running in cycles.